# ServerFault user flair doesn't show up when using the script, but does with an iframe

Tags: support, status-norepro, flair

I keep my user flair icon on my Blogger based blog. I noticed this morning that it's gone. The unmolested script is still in the page. Nonetheless, I copied and pasted the script from ServerFault lest something had changed in it recently (it hadn't, but I did it anyway because I'm like that). Still nothing. I used the iframe option and that worked.

Is anyone else missing their `<script>` user flair icon?

Comment: Working fine on my site. All of them are working actually.

Comment: Fine here as well.

Comment: Curioser and curioser.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem.

My ServerFault flair doesnt show up on any of the Beta sites.

I am registered on both Gaming and Electronic Gadgets but cant see the SF flair on either one of the two. You can see that its suppposed to be there cos the other flair boxes doesnt line up correctly.

[where for art thou ServerFault http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9208331703.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9208331703.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

We can't reproduce this -- possibly an intermittent connectivity issue, or a temporary condition on our side?