# Area 51 logo doesn't render in script form of user flair

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, flair

*Related but different: [ServerFault user flair doesn't show up when using the script, but does with an iframe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38832/serverfault-user-flair-doesnt-show-up-when-using-the-script-but-does-with-an-if)*

The `<script src=.../users/flair/... .../script>` version of user flair for Area 51 has a broken image, because the user flair for that site has a relative link, rather than an absolute URL to the image, namely "/content/se/favicon.ico".

Since I have failed to host the Area 51 thumbnail on my laptop in the place the script kindly requests, the fault for this unintended behaviour is clearly mine.

Notes:

1. This doesn't affect any of the other 3 SX sites I've looked at, or any of the SOFU sites.
2. I've seen the behaviour for a long time now, but only got around to reporting it now.  I'm kind of suprised no one else sees it: I've seen it on Safari on Mac Os 10.4, and Firefox 3.6 on both the same mac and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this -- it's fixed now.